# Error when trying to list users in odoo 14

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

When I go to settings in users I'm getting the following error:

> Invalid field 'documents_account_settings' on model
> 'res.config.settings'

I've been looking at the base code and it seems like the field **documents_account_settings** is not in the model anymore,
the file I've been looking at is this **/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/res_config_settings.py**

is there any known bug related to this?

This is the complete trace is the following:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_http.py", line 237, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 683, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 359, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 94, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 347, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 912, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 531, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1377, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1369, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 394, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_model_create(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_model_create
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-188>", line 2, in create
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 323, in _model_create_single
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/addons/account/models/res_config_settings.py", line 176, in create
    return super(ResConfigSettings, self).create(values)
  File "<decorator-gen-64>", line 2, in create
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 344, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_fields.py", line 533, in create
    recs = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in create
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 345, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3818, in create
    raise ValueError("Invalid field %r on model %r" % (key, self._name))
Exception

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 639, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 315, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
ValueError: Invalid field 'documents_account_settings' on model 'res.config.settings'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the installed app `documents_account` from this it will be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, when we (developers) need something input from admin, we will create a field in `res.config.settings` to get it, so if you looked for it in module `account`, you may never see it, it is created by another module. This error caused you by not installing the right module, or more specify, you are opening a view where it show this field (`documents_account_settings`) but you don't have that field in your database.

There are 2 things (which I know) you can do in this situation to make it better:

- Find where this field is created in your source code, and update or install that module, or easier (for Odoo users), update module `base`, it may reset problem module(s) in your database.
- If you are a developer (which I prefer if true), you can go to your database, table `ir_ui_view`, find which view created that problem (inherit view named 'res.config.settings.view.form') and then alter the architecture part of it.

Hope you find this helping, because I can just show you the way to archive your goals, can not do it for you.